Gnome password field in lock screen loses focus
Sometimes when I wake up the computer after suspend, I notice that the password field loses focus while I am typing the password. I am unable to move the focus by pressing tab. The only way is to use the mouse to click on the field. Is there any suggestion why this happens? There seems to be some record of other users experiencing similar issue. Does this have issue have a solution?
